# Disk Utility Restore from 'Macintosh HD' or 'Macintosh HD - Data'?

Tags: disk-utility, restore

When cloning an HDD with macOS Catalina `Disk Utility`'s Restore, should I restore from 'Macintosh HD' or 'Macintosh HD - Data'? Does it make a difference?

Comment: restore from `Macintosh HD`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloning can include copying from other volumes beyond just the `Macintosh HD` and the `Macintosh HD - Data` APFS volumes. There are also the preboot and recovery APFS volumes within the same APFS container. Since the `Macintosh HD` volume is the root volume when booted to macOS, you should specify this volume when using Disk Utility to restore.